Google Calendar Auth ASP.NET Core
I am upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 4 project to ASP.NET Core and am trying to upgrade Google Calendar integration.
Is there any working examples of Google auth with ASP.NET Core, they had examples with previous versions, but I can't find newer ones.
I have seen articles here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0
But I am unsure if this is trying to configure Google auth into the application itself, which I don't want, I am just trying to auth so I can retrieve information from Google Calendar.

Just a friendly warning.: What ever you do dont try to use the Google .net client library it really doesn't work very well there are serval bugs that you can read about here 2225

The article you have shared is configure the google auth inside the asp.net core,  it will redirect to the google to get the token or else, then you could use that token to get the calendar information.
